# Mercurial repository backup when hidden files can not be backupped

Tags: mercurial, backup

Our company policy is not to back up hidden folders. 
Is it possible to change the .hg folder name to something visible?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to rename that directory using standard mercurial configuration options.  If you're on unix, and I'm guessing your are if .hg sounds hidden, you could use a pre-backup script (or cron job) to snapshot it using `cp -al` into something with a different name.  Using `-l` gets you hardlinks, so it won't actually take up extra disk.

However, most people back up their .hg repositories with a `push` to a different mercurial server, which can be easily scripted too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a tar archive of the repository before your company's backup cycle runs via cron?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to fool the back up system by creating a link to the .hg folder with a "backupable" name.